# Inequalities with arctan

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I don't understand how to solve inequalities with arctan, such as:

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)\ge \frac{\pi}{4} $$

If someone could solve this and give me a very brief explanation of what they did, I'd be thankful.

Comment: Apply tangent to both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps
$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)\ge \frac{\pi}{4} $$
$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}\ge \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}\ge 1$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}-1\ge 0$$
$$\frac{1-x^2+1}{x^2-1}\ge 0$$
$$\frac{2-x^2}{x^2-1}\ge 0$$
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-x\right)\left(x+\sqrt{2}\right)}{(x+1)(x-1)}\ge 0$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

As $-\dfrac\pi2\le\arctan y\le\dfrac\pi2$ and $\arctan$ is increasing function,

we need $$\frac1{x^2-1}\ge\tan\frac\pi4=1$$

$$\iff0\le\frac1{x^2-1}-1=\frac{2-x^2}{x^2-1}$$

$$\iff\frac{x^2-2}{x^2-1}\le0$$

If $x^2-1=0,\arctan\dfrac10=\dfrac\pi2>\dfrac\pi4$

Else $$\frac{x^2-2}{x^2-1}\le0\iff(x^2-2)(x^2-1)\le0\iff1\le x^2\le2$$

Comment: So, basically... arctan(a)=b is equal to tan(b)=a ?

Comment: @Ferduun, Yes, provided $b$ lies in the range specified. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values